Firebase Dynamic Link: iPhone-Generated Link Not Working on Android
I'm experiencing an issue with Firebase Dynamic Links (firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.4.5) where links generated on an iPhone device don't function correctly when opened on Android. Here's a breakdown of the behavior:

Sharing a post iPhone to iPhone: Works as expected.
Sharing a post Android to iPhone: Works as expected.
Sharing a post Android to Android: Works as expected.
Sharing a post iPhone to Android: Fails with a 404 error when the link (https://myappname.app/postId) is opened on the Android device.

Expected Behavior:
The link should seamlessly open the relevant content within my Android app, regardless of the generating device (iPhone or Android).
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified functionality for other scenarios (as mentioned above).
Reviewed Firebase documentation on Dynamic Links.

Additional Context:

I noticed a similar issue reported on GitHub (https://github.com/topics/firebase-dynamic-links), but it was closed without a definitive solution.

Request:
Has anyone else encountered this specific behavior with Firebase Dynamic Links?
Are there any known workarounds or solutions to ensure iPhone-generated links function correctly on Android?
Please Note:
This issue seems similar to the one reported on GitHub, but I'm hoping to gain more insights and potential solutions from the Stack Overflow community.
Thank you for your assistance!
